# gitignore pattern for autogenerated folder

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

I run a script in my project that would generate a temporary folder in the project root. For example `_MEIxX7G6H`, and `ts-node-94a6b447580330f9f2b609422537b04239ff3a39df9137e32efd559f1a2935cb`.

That temporary folder is not meant to be in source control (Git).

It makes no sense to add those names to `.gitignore` because the names change after each execution.

Is there any way to add some pattern to partially match those file names?

Comment: Why can't you just leave that folder as being untracked?  Or, is there anyway you can direct the output of that script outside the project root?

Comment: Can you change the code to generate a common prefix for the temporary directories? Do they have at least the same length?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @TimBiegeleisen, but that's not my question. I want the folder to be explicitely ignored. I can't do as suggested, they are generated by `npm` command in the command line

Comment: @choroba, unfortunately not, it is generated automatically by command `npm`. Yes, I think they are all the same length

Comment: You should provide more examples. The question is currently too specific and your answer too generic. Also note that `.gitignore` does not contain regular expressions but glob expressions. I corrected the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

```
# Will ignore folders prefixed with underscore
_*
# Will ignore folders prefixed with ts-node
ts-node*
```